# Extension and CodeDomProvider

Tags: .net, vb.net, codedom

I am having problems with CodeDomProvider. When I compile a code VB, there is not an error. But, if this code has extensions (ex:  `string().contains()`, `char().count`, `char().AsEnumerable`, etc.) at the moment that I call these functions, it's returns an exception equal for all these extensions:

'Public Member 'Count' at type 'Char()' not found'

'Public Member 'Contains' at type 'String()' not found'

```
Dim refs() As String = {"mscorlib.dll", "System.dll", "Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll","system.xml.dll", "system.core.dll", "system.data.dll"}

oCParams.ReferencedAssemblies.AddRange(refs)
```

These are the Assembly that is referenced to the compile, and this is also configurated for run in Framework 4.0.

```
    Dim Param As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

    Param.Add("CompilerVersion", "v4.0")

    Dim oCodeProvider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("VisualBasic", Param)
```

This code is inside a string:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Collections
Imports System.Linq.Expressions
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.String
Imports System.Linq.Enumerable
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute

Namespace Teste
Class Classe
Public Shared Function ProcessarLink(ByVal URL As System.Uri) As Boolean
Dim QueryString = URL.Query.Remove(0, 1).Split("&"c).tolist

If QueryString.Contains("xxx") Then
...
End If

End Function 
Public Shared Function Personalizar(ByRef Vetor() As Char) As System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of String,Object) 
...
Dim Total As Integer = Vetor.Count
...
End Function 
End Class 
End Namespace
```

After I use it for compile my Assembly.

The code compiles without errors, but when I call the function 'ProcessarLink', it returns me the exception in 'Contains', or when I call the function 'Personalizar' the errors appears with the 'Count'. This happens with the others extensions too, like AsEnumerable, etc.

What is the problem?

Comment: How do you create the code? How does the code look like if you compile it into string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your codefile needs to import the extension methods - i.e. it doesn't include:

```
Imports System.Linq
```

Have you done that? If not, can you post an example vb codefile where you are seeing the errors?

Comment: The example is in the original post. The error occurs even when I import System.Linq.

Comment: Can you try turning on `Option Strict` for the compilation - this might help identify the error

Comment: It fixed the problem. I was declaring the variables without using the 'As'. Using Visual Studio 2010 I had no problems, but when I create my own compilation, the strict forced me to declarate the variables using the 'As' and with this the problem desappeared. i just did not understand why in the VS 2010 the problem doesn't happen. Thank you very much!